# Apache won't allow multiple name-based virtual hosts

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

Here's the problem I'm facing: I've added multiple virtual hosts(name based) to apache yet still only one is loaded.

For example I have two domains with different contents.
Site1 Domain -> Site1 Content 
Site2 Domain -> Site1 Content aswell..
I've included the httpd-vhosts file in the httpd config file, and I've edited it to match what it asks me to do on their documentation yet still only one folder of contents is served.

Here is my httpd-vhosts file, the httpd file I assume doesn't need posting but if required I shall:

```
NameVirtualHost *
<Directory "C:/www/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all

</Directory>
<VirtualHost *>
    ServerName www.*****.com
    DocumentRoot "C:\www*****"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *>
    ServerName ****.co.cc
    DocumentRoot "C:\www\****"
</VirtualHost>
```

ofcourse I removed the unnecessary comments and my domains names(private reasons). Oh yeah, and my server is hosted on Windows Server 2008 Standard

Answer (score 1):

First off, can you check the log files for errors when you start up Apache?  It might be complaining, and it will give very useful information if it does..

Secondly, are you making similar changes to the SSL side of things?  MOD_SSL is handled via a different config file, and if you're trying to access these sides of things on port 443, you're not going to get all the different sites working.

Answer (score 0):

On the surface of it, your config seems fine. How are you accessing these site?
Are you including the Virtual Hosts config at the bottom of httpd.conf?

Answer (score 0):

> For example I have two domains with
>   different contents.
>
> Site1 Domain -> Site1 Content Site2
>   Domain -> Site1 Content aswell..

So which is it? Different content or the same content for both domains?

If its the same content then the correct way is to use the serveralias option:

```
<VirtualHost *>
    ServerName www.firstdomain.com
serveralias firstdomain.com www.seconddomain.com seconddomain.com
    DocumentRoot "C:\www*****"
</VirtualHost>
```

Now you can serve the same content in the manner YOU were trying to do as well. You just have to set the correct document root for domain number 2. In your example the doc root contains a backslash that it shouldn't if the idea is to serve the same content as domain 1.